# Continuity of determinant.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A = \left[\frac{1}{x_i+y_j}\right]$, where $0<x_1<\cdots<x_n, 0<y_1<\cdots<y_n$ are positive real numbers. Then $\det(A)$ is a continuous function of variables $x_i, y_j$.
Suppose $0<\lambda_1<\cdots<\lambda_n, 0<\mu_1<\cdots<\mu_n$ be positive reals such that $\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_i = \alpha = \mu_{i+1}-\mu_i$ for all $1\leq i \leq n-1$, and $\alpha$ is a fixed positive integer.

It can be noted that the set $$ \{ (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in (R^{+})^n: x_{i+1}-x_i = \alpha \quad  \forall \quad  1\leq i \leq n-1 \}$$ is pathwise connected, so connected.

Let $$B = \left[\frac{1}{\lambda_i+\mu_j}\right].$$
Will $det(B)$ be continuous function of positive $\lambda_i, \mu_j$?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Continuous on what set? Do you ensure positivity?

Comment: Yes. It has been edited.

Comment: Note that the connected set you mention is a subset of $\{(x_1,\dots, x_n)\in (R^+)^n: x_1<\cdots<x_n\}$. With that in mind, [does this answer your question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359517/continuity-with-subspaces)

Comment: Just state the composition of continuous functions then

Comment: Can each eigenvalue of this matrix B be a continuous function of $\lambda_i, \mu_j?$

Comment: [Yes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2276042/600276)

Comment: Can you pls give a proper explanation? Because the matrix is not symmetric, so eigenvalues may not be real, that's why we can't put them in a certain order. This way the eigenvalues don't seem to be even a function of $\lambda_i, \mu_j$. Can you please give a proper explanation of your reply. Thanks.